# Save axes handle when plotting In MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, handle, axes

I have script handling figures so that I can `print` and input them in a latex document with scale = 1 and everything looks nice.

In this context I want to save the figure, axes and legend handles.

Is there a way to save them like when using `fig = figure`. I know two 'hacks'

1)

```
nfig = nfig+1; fig = figure(nfig);
plot()
ax = gca
leg = legend()
```

2)

```
nfig = nfig+1; fig = figure(nfig);
ax = subplot(1,1,1)
plot()
leg = legend()
```

My script

```
function  fig_set(fig,ax,leg,width,heigth,font_size)
%% fig_set removes borders and set witdth and height of figure
%
% The function fig_set sets the border of a figure to 0
% and set the width as a scale of the width an a4 paper and the height
% as a scale of the previously set width of the figure.
%
%   Syntax:
%       fig_set(fig,ax,leg,width,heigth,font_size)
%
%   Input:
%       - fig:          figure handl
%       - ax:           axes handle
%       - leg:          legend handle
%       - width:        width of figure, in scales of A4 paper width
%       - height:       height of figure, in scales of width of figure
%       - font_size:    font size of axes and text, it not set default=10
%
%   Output:
%       -figure of handel "fig" with set width, height and font
%       size and Interpreters set to Latex
%
% Auther:   Malthe Vibaek Eisum
% Version:  4.1
% Date:     15/3 - 2016

%% Setting font and font size
if nargin < 3
    error('need figure and axes handle')
elseif nargin < 6
    font_size = 10;
end

%% Setting figure, axes and legende Interpreters to Latex
set(fig,'DefaultTextInterpreter','Latex');
ax.TickLabelInterpreter='Latex';
if leg ~= 0
    leg.Interpreter='Latex';
end

%% Setting width and height of figure
PaperSize = get(0,'defaultFigurePaperSize');
switch fix(PaperSize(1))
    case 8
        Unit = 'inches';
    case 20
        Unit = 'centimeters';
    otherwise
        error('defaultFigurePaperSize is not equivalent to a4 paper')
end
width = PaperSize(1) * width;
height = width * heigth;

 set(fig,'Units',Unit,...
                    'Position',[2 5 width height],...
                    'PaperSize',[width height],...
                    'PaperPositionMode','auto',...
                    'Renderer','painters');
end
```

Example of creating and printing a figure

```
x = 1:3;
y = rand(1,3);
nfig = nfig+1; fig=figure(nfig);
ax = gca;
plot(x,y)
xlabel('$\rho$')
ylabel('more $latex_{math}$')
leg = legend('rand');
fig_set(fig,ax,leg,1,1)
print -depsc2 myplot.eps
```

Comment: Why can't you use `fig = figure`? I don't understand the purpose of `nfig`

Comment: @Daniel It looks like it is inside some loop, so `fig(ii)=figure('property',<value>)` would be better.

Comment: I need `TickLabelInterpreter` which is not a property of figure, but a property of the axes `get(ax,'TickLabelInterpreter')` @Daniel `nfig` is a counter

Comment: Just call `fig=figure()` to create a new figure. No need for a counter.

Comment: Or you can use `ax{ii}=axes('TickLabelInterpreter',<value>)` before `plot` command. Later `get(ax{ii},...)` will return appropriate property.

Comment: Possible related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39852580/54964

Answer (score 1):

Unless you close them, you shoudl be able to do

```
nfig = nfig+1; 
fig{nfig} = figure(nfig);
plot()
ax{nfig} = gca
leg{nfig} = legend()
```

Comment: Wouldn't be `ax{nfig}`=axes();plot()` more elegant. And why you are using cell arrays to keep handles? I use `ax(ii)` because I can easily set properties of all axes by `set(ax,...)`.

Comment: @Crowley I was thinking in case this is MATLAB 2014b, not sure if you can store the handle in an array, I think you need a cell

Comment: In Matlab2011b there is no problem with handle arrays nor with struct arrays.

Comment: @Crowley I know, but in MATLAB 2014a or older, fig, axes and other handles are stored as doubles in the workspace. In newer versions, they are *objects*, thus you can not store them in a numeric array. you dont use `set(ax,'XtickLabel',..)` but `ax.XtickLabel=...`

Comment: Bugger it... Good to know... And I suppose all handles are *objects* in newer versions.

Comment: @Crowley they are. dont get me wrong, `set` still works, so backwards compatibility is there for that, but still, you can not store them in a numeric array!

Comment: @AnderBiguri I dont see the difference in your suggestion then my 'hack' nr.1 (except that you save every handle and not only the one currently working on) I'm looking for a way to save them as I make them

Comment: @MaltheEisum save them to where? memory? this code saves the handles so you can use them later.... There is a difference with your code, as yours does not save them, but rewritte them. What do you mean "save"? `print`, `save`, store as variable ? I assumed last. Cosider addding the code that saves, as we cant read your mind, unfortunatedly

Comment: @AnderBiguri, See post edit. I'm asking how to store axes handle for later edit if not using `gca` or `subplot`

Comment: @MaltheEisum why does my answer not solve your problems? I dont understand, that is exactly what I am doing. when you call `fig_set` call it as `fig_set(fig{index},ax{index},lab{index},....)` as many times needed

Comment: @AnderBiguri you misunderstand me your answer will solve it (as my own also would). My question is, since I can call `gca` Get Current Axes, the axes must have been made at one point it is at this point I want to save it to a variable

Comment: @MaltheEisum teh axes are made when you create a figure, without you explicitly needing to create them. Why gca is bad for you? What is the problem with that? Do you have a *different* code where this is a problem? If so, start from there. you can use `axes()` also, but it wont make a difference in the result

Comment: @MaltheEisum unless you call `axes` explicitly, it is the `plot` call that creates the axes in the current figure if no `CurrentAxes` exists. You cannot get the axes handle directly from `plot`

Comment: @AnderBiguri @Crowley arrays of objects are fine in R2014b+, cell arrays are not needed. However, if the array is initialized as a numeric one, the handles will be stored as doubles (use [`gobjects`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gobjects.html) instead).

Answer (score 1):

```
nfig=nfig+1;                            %// raise the counter
Fig{nfig}=figure();                     %// create nfig-th figure
Ax{nfig}=axes('parent',Fig{Nfig});      %// create nfig-th axes and bind them to nfig-th figure
plot()                                  %// plot a curve
Leg{nfig}=legend(Ax{nfig},'Label1',...);%// assign nfig-th label to nfig-th axes

%% Some other code %%

get(Ax{12},'TickLabelInterpreter')      %// get the interpreter of 12-th axes (in 12-th figure)
set(Ax{5},'xlim',[-10,10])              %// set the x-limits of 5-th axes
```

I hope it is what you are looking for.