# Why axes handle deleted in Matlab loop?

Tags: matlab, error-handling, event-handling, matlab-figure

Code which tries to mimic the real dynamic condition

```
clear all; close all; 

hFig2=figure('Units','inches', 'Name', 'Time'); 
hax2=axes(hFig2); 
movegui(hFig2, 'southeast'); 

index=1; 
while (index < 7);
    hFig2=figure(hFig2); 

    u=0:0.01:1+index;
    plot(hax2, u); % Give columns 1xXYZ to Matlab 
    hold on; 
    axis(hax2, 'xy');

    axis(hax2, [0 (size(u,2)/1 - 0) min(u) max(u)]); % to maximise size  
    axis(hax2, 'off'); % no ticks

    index=index+1;
    pause(1); 
    hold off; 
    drawnow    
end;
```

Logs 1 `hax2` in more dynamic condition, 
Logs 2 `hax2` mostly in Code

```
%% Logs 1 in dynamic condition with failure output
% Failure in more dynamic conditions because axes get deleted for some reason
% hax2
% 
% hax2 = 
% 
%   handle to deleted Axes
% 
%% Logs 2 mostly in Code condition and correct because
% hax2 = 
% 
%   Axes with properties:
% 
%              XLim: [0 201]
%              YLim: [0 2]
%            XScale: 'linear'
%            YScale: 'linear'
%     GridLineStyle: '-'
%          Position: [0.1300 0.1100 0.7750 0.8150]
%             Units: 'normalized'
```

Error if failure in `hax2` i.e. `handle to deleted axes` for some reason

```
%% Failure message
%  Show all properties
%
% Warning: MATLAB has disabled some advanced graphics rendering features by switching to software OpenGL. For more information, click
% here. 
% Error using plot
% Invalid handle.
% 
% Error in test_invalid_handle (line 12)
%     plot(hax2, u);
```

Some tentative proposals of solutions

1. Save the `axes` handle at the end of each loop; possible related thread [Save axes handle when plotting In MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36018727/54964)
2. ...

OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Matlab: 2016a
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
Linux kernel: 4.6 of backports

Comment: I suggest [reading the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `axes`, the first input should be a parameter/value pair that specifies the parent. If you pass it a single handle graphics input it assumes that input is a *handle to an `axes`*

```
axes(hFig2)

% Error using axes
% Invalid axes handle
```

Or as you have it written

```
hax2 = axes(hFig2);

% Error using axes
% Too many output arguments.
```

Because you are passing an invalid `axes` handle to it, it doesn't properly assign the handle to a new `axes` to `hax2`. It is likely that your deleted `hax2` that you're seeing is from a *previous* run of the script.

Instead, you'll want to use parameter/value pairs to specify the `Parent` property of the `axes`.

```
hax2 = axes('Parent', hFig2);
```

Also, I would remove the extraneous call to `figure` every time through the loop since you explicitly specify the parent object of each plot object

Comment: @Masi No, just delete that line entirely. You already define `hFig2` outside of the loop

Comment: @Masi There is no overloading. What do you mean? Just remove the line, you won't have issues

Comment: By disabling all such lines in my code, I get this error `Error using plot
Invalid handle. Error test_code (line 625) plot(hax2, u');`. I really do not understand its origin. If I have such "overloading", I do not get the error.

Comment: @Masi Which lines did you delete? You should only delete a single line (`hFig2 = figure(hFig2)`)

Comment: Yes, I only deleted such lines as `hFig2 = figure(hFig2)`.

Comment: @Masi What do you mean by "such lines". It's *one* line.

Comment: I have 10 such figure lines in my full code. All figures are plotted by `plot` or `imagsc()`. Not all figures use `axes()`.

Comment: @Masi If removing that line causes issues, then don't remove it. Since you haven't provided your entire code it's hard to guess what should be going wrong.